# Looping on array

Tags: ruby

I'm having some trouble figuring out the right way to do this:

I have an array and a separate array of arrays that I want to compare to the first array.  The first array is a special `Enumerable` object that happens to contain an array.

Logic tells me that I should be able to do this:

```
[1,2,3].delete_if do |n|
  [[2,4,5], [3,6,7]].each do |m|
    ! m.include?(n)
  end
end
```

Which I would expect to return
    => [2,3]

But it returns `[]` instead.

This idea works if I do this:

```
[1,2,3].delete_if do |n|
  ! [2,4,5].include?(n)
end
```

It will return

```
 => [2]
```

I can't assign the values to another object, as the `[1,2,3]` array must stay its special `Enumerable` object.  I'm sure there is a much simpler explanation to this than what I'm trying.  Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the return value of `each` is the array being iterated over, not the boolean (which is lost). Since the array is truthy, the value returned back to `delete_if` is always true, so all elements are deleted. You should instead use [`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F):

```
[1,2,3].delete_if do |n|
  ![[2,4,5], [3,6,7]].any? do |m|
    m.include?(n)
  end
end
#=> [2, 3]
```

Comment: This seems to have gotten me where I need to be.  I knew I was over complicating it.  Thanks!

Comment: `select` in stead of `delete_if` gets rid of the `!`.

Comment: @steenslag But `select` doesn't modify the array in place, whereas `delete_if` does, so it'd have to be `select!`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also flatten the multi-dimensional array and use the [Array#&](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-26) intersection operator to get the same result:

```
# cast your enumerable to array with to_a
e = [1,2,3].each
e.to_a & [[2,4,5], [3,6,7]].flatten
# => [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add the two inner array together, and and check the inclusion on the concatenated array?

```
[1,2,3].delete_if do |n|
  !([2,4,5] + [3,6,7]).include?(n)
end
```

Comment: This will not work as I have an arbitrary number of inner arrays.

Comment: Better `[[2,4,5], [3,6,7]].flatten`, then it works with any number of arrays.

Comment: Or `[[2,4,5], [3,6,7,5]].flatten.uniq` if there are possible duplicates in your arrays.